# How to block/cut download pdf file in specific field from database?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to block connection download from certain field that I don't want public to know it.

I tried to use some `if else` method but it didn't work.

This is My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/path/{idUser}/{idDocumentType}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadDocumentForPublic(@PathVariable("idUser") Integer idUser, @PathVariable("idDocumentType") Integer idDocumentType, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
  try 
  {
    UserDocumentUpload doc = UserDocumentUploadService.idUserDocumentForPublicDownload(idUser, idDocumentType);
    if (doc != null) 
    {
      File file = userFileService.latestUserDocumentUpload(doc);

      String contentType = userFileService.getResponseContentTypeByFileExtension(file);
      MediaType mediaType = FileUtil.getMediaType(file);
      response.setContentType(contentType);
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" + dok.getOriginalFilename() + "\"");

      InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

      ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

      IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
      inputStream.close();
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();
    }

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (MimeTypeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I expect to block `{idDocumentType}` = number `13`? 

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: if ( idDocumentType == 13 ) return; but your code looks like an upload, not a download

Comment: @Stultuske yeah but my certain url got crawl by googlebot then i have to block it. and i already did that if (idDocumentType == 13 ) return = 0; but i got error parsing? help mee